# How to scan network for intel vpro computers?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, intel

Ive seen an example in the docs of Intel AMT SDK but it takes so long to tell me that is there 1 intel vpro pc in my network and it doesnt tell me the name or ip address of that pc.

Is there a way to get the name and ip address of intel vpro computers in my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a resource that we published recently on the Intel vPro Expert Center - it details different ways to find the Intel vPro PCs on your network: [How To Find Intel® vPro™ Technology Based PCs](http://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-5693).

Michele Gartner
Community Manager
Intel vPro Expert Center

Comment: Hi Michele, welcome to Server Fault. We love to see companies actively participate in the Q&A here. If you haven't already check out the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). Signature lines are normally discouraged, but your also required to make it obvious if you're associated with any productions/solutions that you suggest. Thank you for your contribution and we hope you'll become a frequent visitor.

Answer (score 3):

You could just scan for TCP port 9971.

Or ports 16992/16993 for already provisioned intel vpro platforms.

Answer (score 1):

This Getting Started Guide should point you in the right direction
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-active-management-technology-intel-amt-software-development-kit-sdk-start-here-guide/